# change templateUrl in routeProvider based on user permission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I want to change the templateUrl on the router provider based on the user permission like the following :

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/',{
    if(user)
        templateUrl:'app/views/pages/home-page.html'
    else if(admin) 
        templateUrl:'app/views/pages/admin-page.html'
  })
```

I have a query that returns to me the permission of the user, then if the user is admin I should redirect him to admin-homepage ?
what is the best practice to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `routeChange` event (you can add this code to your `app.run`):

In your **`app.run`**:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  if(next.$$route.originalPath = '/' && user) {
      $location.path('/home');
  }         
});
```

Comment: I used this and got the following error TypeError: Cannot set property 'originalPath' of undefined ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdALKareem `next` is the next route (where you are going to). Try to inspect this object to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

`templateUrl` accepts a function as a value, for dynamic routing values.

From the docs:

> "If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following parameters:
>
> {Array.} - route parameters extracted from the current $location.path() by applying the current route"

You can either use this function to run your if statement logic, acting like middleware, or apply a function that does the logic, constructs your dynamic template and returns it.

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: _ => { //you're not using a dynamic file name here
        let route = 'app/views/pages/';
        if (user) route += 'home-page.html';
        else if (admin) route += 'admin-page.html';
        return route;
    }
})
```

You can take this one step further and actually apply the parameter, which will add a dependency to your URL. Now, the middleware will change here because both accept the same value, so you'll have to change the function to check permissions on both layers, or apply different URL scopes.

Example with `$http`. Obviously I don't know your whole schema, to take `.isUser`, `isAdmin`, and `url/for/permissions` as things you need to change.

```
$http.get('/url/for/permissions/').then(results => {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: _ => { //you're not using a dynamic file name here
            let route = 'app/views/pages/';
            if (results.isUser) route += 'home-page.html';
            else if (results.isAdmin) route += 'admin-page.html';
            return route;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: can I make an http request inside this function to get the permission ?

Comment: Yes, but since it's async, you'll maybe want to check for permissions before the routeProvider runs

Comment: Great ! can you update the answer with an example of that  ?

Comment: Sure, something like this should help out

Comment: Thank you very much , you are really helpful !

Comment: Ok one more thing , i need the user when try to access  this route '/' to make an http request to check the permission of the user and then redirect him to his page ! I think the code up doesn't do that